# Thread local storage memory usage

Tags: c#, thread-local-storage

Is there a way in .NET to determine the amount of memory being taken up by thread-local storage?

Specifically, I'm looking to find the amount of memory used by ThreadStatic objects and by memory allocated to objects in the Thread data slots (e.g. by calling Thread.SetData).

To clarify:

Thread-local storage:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sby1byh.aspx

Thread Local Storage: Thread-Relative Static Fields and Data Slots
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sby1byh.aspx

Comment: How do you define "the amount of memory being taken up by thread-local storage"?

Comment: My guess is that the slots are going to take up a very tiny amount of space, what your are really interested in is the amount of data in the heap that is referenced by the slots, counting that is pretty tricky cause you would have to walk an object graph.

Comment: @Sam Exactly what I was looking for. But I don't even see an API that allows me to list the contents of the slots.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the memory usage by process as below. There are several other memory measurements that you can use [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process_properties.aspx). But, I am not quite sure whether there is a way to get the memory usage by thread. Process has [Threads property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.threads.aspx) which consists of a collection of [ProcessThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.aspx)s which is exactly what you are interested in, but not straight forward way to get the memory usage.

```
// Get the current process.
Process currentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();

// Gets the amount of physical memory allocated for the associated process.
long totalNumberOfBytesUsed = currentProcess.WorkingSet64;
```